# Flutter pub get, Dependencies version solving failed. error

Tags: flutter, dependencies, flutter-dependencies

I'm trying to run pub get on my terminal and getting this error messages.

```
Because google_maps_webservice 0.0.20-nullsafety.5 depends on http ^0.13.0 and no versions of google_maps_webservice match
  >0.0.20-nullsafety.5 <0.1.0, google_maps_webservice ^0.0.20-nullsafety.5 requires http ^0.13.0.
And because google_maps_place_picker_mb >=2.0.0-mb.14 depends on google_maps_webservice ^0.0.20-nullsafety.5, google_maps_place_picker_mb      
  >=2.0.0-mb.14 requires http ^0.13.0.
So, because explore_places depends on both http ^1.1.0 and google_maps_place_picker_mb ^3.0.1, version solving failed.
```

And I have tried to change the versions according to the error message but still facing the same issue.

this is my dependency override look like :

```
dependency_overrides:
  http: 1.1.0
  flutter_html: 2.2.1
  xml: ^6.3.0
  wakelock: ^0.6.2
  win32: ^5.0.2
  flutter_math_fork: ^0.7.1
  flutter_svg: ^1.0.0
```

google map

```
  maps_launcher: ^2.2.0
  geolocator: ^9.0.2
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.2.7

  google_maps_place_picker_mb: 3.0.1
```

and my connectivity look like

```
  http: ^1.1.0
  connectivity_plus: ^4.0.1
  cached_network_image: ^3.2.3
  html: ^0.15.3
  package_info_plus: ^4.0.1
  flutter_html: 2.2.1
```

I have tried `flutter channel stable` -> `flutter pub upgrade` -> `flutter pub get`
but it did not solve my issue either.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your some of your google packages are outdated means they are using different package versions of http or others.

Only thing you can do is finding the alternate packages